# For all Dirichlet series, is $a_n$ unique to $f(s)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, dirichlet-series

For any Dirichlet series, $$f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$$ is the sequence, $a_n$, always unique to $f(s)$?  In other words, is it possible to show that $a_n$ is the *only* sequence that will ever satisfy the series being equal to $f(s)$?

If this is not true, could someone try to provide a counter example if possible?

Comment: (Assuming you mean $x(s)$) I would try to assume $a_n\not\equiv b_n$ give rise to the same function. Then if $c_n=a_n-b_n$ we have $g(s) = \sum \frac{c_n}{n^s} = 0$. As $s\to\infty$ the lowest non-zero term $\frac{c_k}{k^s}$ will dominate the sum. Then try to prove that $c_k$ has to be zero which would contradict it being the lowest non-zero term so we must have $c_n\equiv 0$. I don't know if there are any subtleties here that would obstruct such a proof.

Comment: What is $s$? Is it a fixed number?

Comment: Interesting @Winther.  I'm not quite sure how to go about proving that $c_k$ has to be zero... and thank you. I will fix that.

Comment: You should clarify if you mean $x$ as just a number or $x(s)$ as a function. In the first case the statement is certainly *not* true.

Comment: $s$ is a fixed number @Wojowu.

Comment: If we take $s=1$, this isn't true. Example: first take $a_1=1,a_n=0$ otherwise, second take $a_2=a_3=a_6=1,a_n=0$ otherwise. They both give $x=1$. (edit: now you changed the question, so this invalidates my comment).

Comment: See [here for another proof using Perron's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2568257/43288)

Comment: This is 11.3 in Apostol's book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that your series converges absolutely for all large $s$, then, yes, expansion of $f(s)$ as Dirichlet series is unique.  See Theorem 4.8 at http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/ant/main4.pdf for proof.

Otherwise, you should be able to provide a counterexample.

Comment: Then what do we say about things like convergence acceleration methods? For instance for apery's constant $\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^3}$ we can let $a_n=1$ or $a_n=\frac 52 (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1{\binom {2n}n}$

Comment: @Ty O'Brien For all $s > 1$, $$\zeta(s) \neq \frac{5}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\binom{2n}{n} n^s}.$$  I plotted those two functions and saw that they have different graphs, but happen to intersect at $s = 3$.  I see now in one of your comments that you want $s$ to be a fixed number, so my answer is not appropriate.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. My comment says that there are two different values of $a_n$ such that the sum of $\frac{a_n}{n^3}$ equals $\zeta(3)$.  In fact there are others as well such as $a_n=\frac 43 (-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: @Ty O'Brien I was referring to your comment on Sep 1 '15 at 17:11.

To be clear, if one is considering $f(s)$ for *all* values of $s$ where the Dirichlet series converges absolutely (i.e., the *entire* function for those large $s$), then the $a_n$ are unique.  That is what my answer means.  But as Winther notes in his second comment, if one is considering just one value of the function, then the $a_n$ are not unique.  Both Wojowu and you give examples.

To visualize, note that even though two different functions have different graphs, they can still share a common point of intersection.

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know I've accepted your answer but I guess I'm not satisfied about one thing.  What do we say about the zeta function when we define $a_n$ in terms of $s$? Because $a_n$ can equal $1$ or $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{1-2^{1-s}}$ and they are equal for all $s\gt 1$

Comment: @Ty O'Brien By the definition of a Dirichlet series, $a_n$ is not a function of $s$.  Your second case, therefore, is not a Dirichlet series and so does not contradict my answer or comments.