# How to extract coefficients from Dirichlet series.

Tags: dirichlet-series

I know, there was a similar question like this:
[Can the coefficients of a Dirichlet series be recovered?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836928/can-the-coefficients-of-a-dirichlet-series-be-recovered)
But i can see that in case when given function(series) has only positive real numbers as a domain, then Perron's formula is useless here.
Could someone show me a other way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two ways to find the coefficients : either look at $\lim_{s \to \infty} F(s)$ to find $f(1)$ then at $\lim_{s \to \infty} n^s (F(s)-\sum_{m=1}^n f(m) m^{-s})$ to find $f(n)$, or note that $f(n)n^{-\sigma} = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2T} \int_{-T}^T F(\sigma+2i\pi t) n^{it} dt$ for $\sigma$ larger than the abscissa of absolute convergence.

Comment: But i don't understand the second way. I wrote that given function is determined only for pure real (and positive) numbers.

Comment: By Perron's formula (see Apostol's book, Chapter 11), we have that $$f(x) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-T}^T F(\sigma+\imath t) x^{\sigma+\imath t} dt,$$ for $\sigma > \sigma_F$ such that the Dirichlet series $F$ is absolutely convergent.